# How to read dynamic json in request using nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am getting `json` like this in `post` in `nodejs`:

```
{  
   "action":"4",
   "enter":{  
      "login":"loginname"
   },
   "data_1":{  
      "order":"0",
      "time":"19:12:10 2017-07-05",
      "message":"Loop 0",
      "type":"test_type"
   },
   "data_2":{  
      "order":"1",
      "time":"19:12:11 2017-07-05",
      "message":"Loop 1",
      "type":"test_type"
   },
   "data_3":{  
      "order":"2",
      "time":"19:12:11 2017-07-05",
      "message":"Loop 2",
      "type":"test_type"
   }
}
```

There is a `data` node, how can I iterate (DYNAMIC) over all `data` nodes and print `message`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This JSON is not possible as because of same key is repeating. Please check the JSON. Keys need to be unique in JSON or else you can retrieve only last similar key data.

Comment: Hi @Shiladitya what about now, when I add _number after every node.

Comment: Now it's possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/6gze9occ/

```
var data = {  
  "action":"4",
  "enter":{  
  "login":"loginname"
 },
 "data_1":{  
  "order":"0",
  "time":"19:12:10 2017-07-05",
  "message":"Loop 0",
  "type":"test_type"
 },
 "data_2":{  
  "order":"1",
  "time":"19:12:11 2017-07-05",
  "message":"Loop 1",
  "type":"test_type"
 },
 "data_3":{  
  "order":"2",
  "time":"19:12:11 2017-07-05",
  "message":"Loop 2",
  "type":"test_type"
 }
};

var keys = Object.keys(data);

for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
   if(typeof data[keys[i]]["message"] !== 'undefined')
       console.log(data[keys[i]]["message"]);
}
```